# How to test if a button is pressed and how to use the console in Flutter (AndroidStudio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, button, console

I am trying to test if a button works in a flutter app.

If I was developing an Android native app, I'd make use of Log.i to print a message in the Logcat.

I want to the same exact thing in flutter.

What I've tried so far:

- debugPrint
- print
- to import 'dart:developer' package to make use of the log function

Apart from this problem, I cannot open the console in AndroidStudio.

Here's a screenshot taken after looking fot the coslone in the search bar:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o13ie.png)

Any help would be appreciated !!!!

Hey there,

I am trying to test if a button works in a flutter app.

If I was developing an Android native app, I'd make use of Log.i to print a message in the Logcat.

I want to the same exact thing in flutter.

What I've tried so far:

- debugPrint ...
- print('BUTTON CLICKED')
- import 'dart:developer' as logDev;  onPressed: () => logDev.log('BUTTON CLICKED', name: 'FAB -> ')

Apart from this problem, I cannot open the console in AndroidStudio.

Here's a screenshot taken after looking fot the coslone in the search bar:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o13ie.png)

Any help would be appreciated !!!!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Also try separating your question into two, when asking for help related to different topics. Can you please share the code you used trying to print something to the console when pressing the button?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.